# I can't start airodump-ng (aircrack-ng)

Tags: aircrack-ng

This is what I get when starting `airodump-ng`

```
root@guido-laptop:/home/guido# airodump-ng wlan0
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead. Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.
```

Comment: "Device or resource busy" Seems to indicate that you're using this network device. Does it help to shut down the Network Manager (`sudo stop network-manager`)? Try again after that and if that still fails, follow the suggestion in the error message you posted.

Comment: I predict your next question to be negative one channel bug.

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to start airodump on a non-monitor interface.

Airodump requires that you run it on a monX interface just like the error message tells you to do.  I'm working on a python conversion for everything but the cracking.  In the mean time, read the directions and run airmon-ng start wlan0 to fix your problem.

It's a little upsetting when the answer is in the error message in the question in total...